# inconsistency Linux server history

Tags: linux, centos, timestamps, history

> We are using cent OS machines for production environment, some times web application [Jboss] is giving hour back time stamp instead of current time. even in server history also having inconsistent time stamps. can any one help me to figure out the issue.

We have verified system date and its proper, web server logs also writing with system date. but only access logs are writing with inconsistent time stamps.

```
### server history : ###


     5471  21/06/17 09:55:11 ls -ltr
     5472  21/06/17 09:55:41 clear
     5473  21/06/17 09:55:42 ls -ltr
     5474  21/06/17 09:55:46 clear
     5475  21/06/17 09:55:50 cd ../../bin/
     5476  21/06/17 09:55:53 sh standalone.sh &
     5477  21/06/17 07:54:53 cd /logdata/
     5478  21/06/17 07:54:55 ls -ltr
     5479  21/06/17 07:54:56 clear
     5480  21/06/17 07:55:04 java DateTime
     5481  21/06/17 08:01:34 date
     5482  21/06/17 08:01:56 clear
     5483  21/06/17 08:01:58 date
     5484  21/06/17 08:03:11 cat /etc/localtime
     5485  21/06/17 08:03:22 date
     5486  21/06/17 08:32:27 jps
     5487  21/06/17 08:32:50 ps -ef|egrep "23670|24538|2420724207"
     5488  21/06/17 08:32:58 ps -ef|egrep "23670|24538|24207"
     5489  21/06/17 09:42:54 jps
     5490  21/06/17 09:43:01 date
     5491  21/06/17 09:43:09 ntpq -l
     5492  21/06/17 09:43:14 ntpq -p
     5493  21/06/17 09:44:08 date
     5494  21/06/17 09:46:09 jps
     5495  21/06/17 09:46:36 pwdx 24538
     5496  21/06/17 09:46:48 pwdx 24207
     5506  21/06/17 09:49:49 pwdx 24538 24207
     5507  21/06/17 08:24:45 jps
     5508  21/06/17 08:24:49 date
     5509  21/06/17 08:24:55 clear
     5510  21/06/17 08:25:50 ifconfig
     5511  21/06/17 08:38:49 clear


###JBOSS Access Log :###

21/Jun/2017:08:46:12 +0100 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-40
21/Jun/2017:08:46:12 +0100 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-40
21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-41
21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-41
21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-41
21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-41
21/Jun/2017:08:52:22 +0100 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-53
21/Jun/2017:08:52:22 +0100 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-53
21/Jun/2017:08:52:22 +0100 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-5
```

Comment: For "server history" are you referring to the .bash_history or ksh's .sh_history file? WRT the JBOSS, the environment, it may be that somehow TZ is set differenty. **Pro Tip:** When possible, always log using UTC or include timezone identified in the log (whether by offset or name).

Comment: Hi @Deathgrip
above is from .bash_history. and server is in BST timezone.

Comment: if timezone issue then complete trace should be on wrong time. 
but some times its giving proper system time and some time not. if you see above logs, you can find the requests on 21/06/17 08:46:12 and next transaction is on 21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 and again 
21/Jun/2017:08:52:22.

Answer (score 0):

The .bash_history is easy. The file doesn't get written line-by-line. It is typically appended when the shell is closed/exited. On multi-user systems this could create the condition shown depending on when multiple people log in and out. For example let us say you logged in via ssh at 08:00. Ran a few commands between 08:00 and 08:05, but didn't log out. You then at 09:00 open an additional ssh session and run a few commands and log out a few minutes after. Later on you notice you have a session open (the one you started at 08:00) and exit. The .bash_history file will append the history from this earlier session (which contains commands from 08:00-08:05) to the commands appended when the session opened at 09:00 exited. I see this all time on servers in a dev environment that have shared/application accounts.

In your JBOSS log, note the `+0100` and `+0000` values after the date and time. I am going to assume these are offsets from UTC. So if you adjust for the offset, the above JBOSS log would read:

```
21/Jun/2017:07:46:12 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-40
21/Jun/2017:07:46:12 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-40
21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-41
21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-41
21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-41
21/Jun/2017:07:47:58 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-41
21/Jun/2017:07:52:22 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-53
21/Jun/2017:07:52:22 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-53
21/Jun/2017:07:52:22 +0000 "POST /resources/v1/messaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139 - default task-5
```

Comment: Thanks @Deathgrip, where can i find the access log related offset settings in jboss? can you help me on this. 

Because this service is running since one year, and we didn't modified anything at server level. but today we have a production update and as a part of update we have deployed new war files.

Comment: I'm not a JBOSS guy, but maybe this link will help you. http://planet.jboss.org/post/step_right_up_and_select_your_time_zone